# How to disable bolt port Neo4j EE 3.2.1

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to run Neo4j EE 3.2.1 on AWS EC2, I was able to access the UI via port 7474, but couldn't connect to DB because `bolt://myip:7687` isn't opened.

I could open this port on security group but prefer that Neo4j connects with DB via localhost instead.

Comment: Were you able to solve it after these 3 years?

Answer (score 0):

On /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

update 
dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=false

Comment: I tried that, then the GUI still asked for bolt host, and then even if I enter the host, it wouldn't let me connect at all.